# Extracting string to variable using regex bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a string which is like:

```
Return-Path: bT.41aywtru20=krja5b54hplm=k29fsc7grl@fake.link.com
Received-SPF: pass (fake.link.com: Sender is authorized to use 'bt.41aywtru20=krja5b54hplm=k29fsc7grl@fake.link.com' in 'mfrom' identity (mechanism 'include:spf.smtp2go.com' matched)) receiver=pmxlab01.permission.email; identity=mailfrom; envelope-from="bt.41aywtru20=krja5b54hplm=k29fsc7grl@fake.link.com"; helo=e2i353.smtp2go.com; client-ip=103.2.141.97
Received: from e2i353.smtp2go.com (e2i353.smtp2go.com [103.2.141.97])
    by mailserver.fake.com(Proxmox) with ESMTP id A4F983E1048
    for <fake@fake.com>; Tue, 24 Aug 2021 14:47:20 +0100 (BST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=smtpcorp.com; s=a1-4; h=Feedback-ID:X-Smtpcorp-Track:Message-Id:Subject:
    Date:To:From:Reply-To:Sender:List-Unsubscribe;
    bh=cTg4MkkE2uaIjpApjJYQFK3RgYiMF3bwCj8UZjFO4NE=; b=STU7lctit7L5LJ2tA3Re1fe4II
    lXJbY/SBXTGqCHh9p4K86aLK5Bvz98Q7eR9xwjFib6x4NoZZ5L1fke0XQERd1eQvxkl9R+kRIGU8A
    QOtrLPpt8coN8P+syoaTRR4pDJQG9OfJO1fON9OaOP8HwnEg/91ie6Cm+wQRxjwyat859uAcu89Xv
    6/mrcequkSp6kfiQN4goZ7vMYJYfBYuooslbTciaK4SYIfxdINyrrWGA6QhJPobdW0uuedRNY5jBG
    OdMbVmm7FTpxDJs51rB1PTIcFQ8W1oypcttqSgCjI+5eMVrabU/IoIxhX5F0Cn3zm7E9CHlaJuLt1
    CRXVbwdw==;
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
 d=fake.com; i=@fakelink.com; q=dns/txt; s=s575655;
 t=1629812840; h=from : subject : to : message-id : date;
 bh=cTg4MkkE2uaIjpApjJYQFK3RgYiMF3bwCj8UZjFO4NE=;
 b=TEeEsPNLf7Wi6b8aaxE6JvfymfBKYjLq7izcUVrOXTW7sGIznxOA5udhfmDh15Fgp6Qgh
 Kv5HX9uPNa8TEeoaJ+gV/4KERuscnc4GXEHwo0eclktx6f6JI5h1/q+qCe34+cN/EweaP5n
 iOs+nrzsRuWn/iQ0Yck+b4IXVWHoTW8298xmBNuC1JF4jIVXREJFAC0nACfGU03OlpjDXf/
 qvI6Ffnn5YGTNxgIkOdrtymaqOvjG9NM0PWtgSkvsTCJdUvxkrI+rRUG6ixiNi+vifqwvox
 aQ6BRnMmeNK7A954Dy9r9r09QzbTthsBsi+lORKH7DntBKhm7Rb5/Q9j0xVA==
Received: from [10.176.58.103] (helo=SmtpCorp) by smtpcorp.com with esmtpsa
 (TLS1.2:ECDHE_SECP256R1__RSA_SHA256__AES_256_GCM:256)
 (Exim 4.94.2-S2G) (envelope-from <tomtest@fakelink.com>)
 id 1mIWls-TRjyEC-AK for fake@fake.com; Tue, 24 Aug 2021 13:47:20 +0000
Received: from [10.86.20.232] (helo=DESKTOP-69OG2R3)
 by smtpcorp.com with esmtpsa (TLS1.2:ECDHE_RSA_SECP256R1__AES_256_GCM:256)
 (Exim 4.94.2-S2G) (envelope-from <fakename@fakelink.com>)
 id 1mIWlr-9EFPsz-U0 for fake@fake.com; Tue, 24 Aug 2021 13:47:19 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: fake@fake2.com
To: fake@fake.com
Date: 24 Aug 2021 14:46:30 +0100
Subject: Test Email 2xM9e5Dj
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary=--boundary_11_ddba370a-13e2-4ffc-8b36-0eb7a5cde80e
Message-Id: <E1mIWlr-9EFPsz-U0@message-id.smtpcorp.com>
X-Smtpcorp-Track: 1XmW_r9EFeszl0.JChXLDDjoy7xH
Feedback-ID: 575655m:575655aVI_MaS:575655sNpPp5WOdD
X-Report-Abuse: Please forward a copy of this message, including all headers,
 to <abuse-report@smtp2go.com>


----boundary_11_ddba370a-13e2-4ffc-8b36-0eb7a5cde80e
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This is a text message
----boundary_11_ddba370a-13e2-4ffc-8b36-0eb7a5cde80e
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This is a html message
----boundary_11_ddba370a-13e2-4ffc-8b36-0eb7a5cde80e--
```

This is stored in a variable called `$emailText`

I'm trying to use a regex to take the From part out of the text

`From: fake@fake2.com`

My regex isnt super strong, however my testing looks like this works: `(?<=From: ).*.`

But when I try and take the text out, it appears I can't get the regex to go through properly.

`echo [[ $emailText =~ (?<=From: ).*. ]]`

Comment: bash regex doesn't support lookbehind or lookahead assertions.

Comment: That regex is more like `PCRE` bash has `ERE`

Comment: You want to use a language with a proper email parsing library, like Python. Getting the literal value of the header is just the first step an any meaningful email processing.

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` regex doesn't support lookbehind or lookahead assertions.

It is much easier to use a non-regex approach using awk here:

```sh
awk -F ': ' '$1 == "From" {print $2}' <<< "$emailText"

fake@fake2.com
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I could be putting it in wrong, but i'm getting the following error
```./test.sh: 27: Syntax error: redirection unexpected```

Comment: @MissCoder87: you're not using Bash

Comment: @MissCoder87: If not using `bash` then use: `echo "$emailText" | awk '$1 == "From:" {print $2}'`

Comment: I see, thank you - i've updated to /bin/bash and it's working perfect thank you

Answer (score 3):

With `bash`:

```
[[ "$emailText" =~ From:\ ([^$'\n']*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Output:

```
fake@fake2.com
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, attempts; please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, checking condition if 1st field is From: then print 2nd field of that line.

```
awk '$1=="From:"{print $2}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** In case you have only 1 entry of `From:` in whole file then try following, where we can use `exit` function to exit from Input_file after printing the matched line, to stop un-necessary reading of whole Input_file.

```
awk '$1=="From:"{print $2;exit}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

If there should be a mail address present, you can match it first using `awk` (without the unsupported need for lookarounds)

```
awk 'match($0, /^From: [^[:space:]@]+@[^[:space:]@]+$/) {
  print $2
}' <<< "$emailText"
```

Output

```
fake@fake2.com
```

Comment: This is only correct for `From:` fields where the terminus alone is present. Most real-world email looks like `From: Real Name <terminus@example.com>` (or, heavens, `From: "Victim, Microsoft" <terminus@example.com>`)

Comment: @tripleee Fair point, if that is the case that printing the second field by default is not guaranteed to work and we need a more sophisticated approach.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only want the email terminus, here's a quick and dirty Awk script.

```sh
awk '/^$/ { exit 1 }
    /^From: .* <[^<>@]+@[^<>]+>/ {
        split($0, g, /[<>]/); print g[1]; exit }
    /^From: / { print $2; exit }' file.eml
```

This should work correctly for all these cases:

```
From: Real Name <real.name@example.com>
From: "Name, Real" <outlook@torture.example.com>
From: terminus@example.com
From: terminus@example.com (Real Name)
From: =?q?utf-8?Real_N=A3=E4me?= <real.name@example.com>
```

As especially the last example should convince you, you will need significantly more work if you also need the full name of the correspondent in normalized form.